# How to name a new table storing location at which transaction occurred

Tags: transaction, event

My client wants to begin collecting data about where transactions occurred.  We have a list of their events and locations where payments might be received, I'm just stumped on what to call the table in my database.
transaction context?

Comment: `transaction_location`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend keeping a few things in mind.  You will want to be consistent no matter what you decide.  For example, will you shorten 'transaction' to 'tx' so all of your stored procedures and scripts are easier to use?  How often will you be changing it?  Here are some good best cases from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions):

Singular names for tables

Singular names for columns

Schema name for tables prefix (E.g.: SchemeName.TableName)

Pascal casing, camel casing, your own casing, but uniform and standard.

Just in case I'll point out that this is an auditing record of transaction data.  I'd keep ACID compliance on the top of my mind if this data is very sensitive and requires to be kept/accurate such as for auditing or billing.

If so, please consider *how* you'll get the data in there with full ACID compliance.  You can update your stored procedures, add triggers/cdc (though those have their own limitations), or keep it within the same transaction for example.

Comment: "*Pascal casing*" is not such a good idea `FooBar` and `FOOBAR` are the same names in (standard) SQL. `snake_case` should be preferred.

Comment: Ah yes, this is hotly debated.  Camel Case and Pascal Casing often draw blood between devs.  I'll stay neutral for this one and modify it :P

Comment: I just wanted to point out that for some DBMS (especially those that follow the SQL standard) `FooBar` will be stored as `FOOBAR` and thus the camel casing doesn't really make sense because it's lost

Comment: All good things to keep in mind, thanks. I'm more looking for a TERM to describe "location where a transaction occurred" from an accounting standpoint.  This may not be the correct exchange for this topic.  Thank you all for your help

Comment: Well put @a_horse_with_no_name.  Thanks.  Good luck BoatCode, it sounds like you're on the right track.